# Working with large images

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, fpdf

I am trying to convert a large jpeg around (1200 x 100) to a PDF document.

I currently am using FPDF and am using this following code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf =& new FPDF('p','pt','a4');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image("photo.jpg");
$pdf->Output("photo.pdf",'F');
?>
```

The PDF is created fine, but the image gets cut off and doesn't display all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, FPDF inserts images at 72dpi unless you specify otherwise, in which case your image comes out at 16.7 x 1.4 inches, which exceeds the page size.

Comment: How can I fix this problem then because that seems to be the issue

Comment: the `->Image()` call has arguments to specify width/height: http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm